# Extracting sub-elements from list of lists vs list of vectors using lapply

Tags: r, lapply

How does `lapply` extract sub-elements from a list? More specifically, how does `lapply` extract sub-elements from a list of lists versus a list of vectors? Even more specifically, suppose I have the following:

```
my_list_of_lists <- list(list(a = 1, b = 2), list(a = 2, c = 3), list(b = 4, c = 5))
my_list_of_lists[[1]][["a"]] # just checking
# [1] 1 
# that's what I expected
```

and apply the following:

```
lapply(my_list_of_lists, function(x) x[["a"]]) 
# [[1]]
# [1] 1
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] 2
# 
# [[3]]
# NULL
```

So `lapply` extracts the `a` element from each of the 3 sublists, returning each in its own list, contained in the length=3 list. At this point, my mental model is the following: `lapply` applies `FUN` to each element of `my_list`, returning `FUN(my_list[[i]])` for `i` in `1:3`. Great! So I expect my mental model should work for lists of vectors as well. For example,

```
my_list_of_vecs <- list(c(a = 1, b = 2), c(a = 2, c = 3), c(b = 4, c = 5))
my_list_of_vecs[[1]][["a"]] # Just checking
# [1] 1
# that's what I expected
```

and apply the following:

```
lapply(my_list_of_vecs, function(x) x[["a"]]) 
# Error in x[["a"]] : subscript out of bounds
# Wait...What!?
```

What's going on here!? Shouldn't this just work? I found a section in `help(lapply)` which might be relevant:

> For historical reasons, the calls created by lapply are unevaluated,
>   and code has been written (e.g., bquote) that relies on this. This
>   means that the recorded call is always of the form FUN(X[[i]], ...),
>   with i replaced by the current (integer or double) index. This is not
>   normally a problem, but it can be if FUN uses sys.call or match.call
>   or if it is a primitive function that makes use of the call. This
>   means that it is often safer to call primitive functions with a
>   wrapper, so that e.g. lapply(ll, function(x) is.numeric(x)) is
>   required to ensure that method dispatch for is.numeric occurs
>   correctly.

I really don't know how to make sense of this.

I think it's related to the fact that you can use both `[[` and `[` extraction of single elements from a vector but you can ONLY use `[` extraction of ranges of elements. For example,

```
my_list_of_vecs[[1]][1:2]
# a b 
# 1 2
my_list_of_vecs[[1]][[1:2]]
# Error in my_list_of_vecs[[1]][[1:2]] : 
#   attempt to select more than one element in vectorIndex
```

So under the hood, `lapply` must be using `function(x) x[["a"]]` over a range. Is that right?

Debugging doesn't help me here since these functions rely on `.Internal` functions.

Comment: This is not a `lapply` issue. It's an issue with the way `[[` works when you pass it an element name that doesn't exist. Try `my_list_of_lists[[3]][["a"]]`

Comment: Yes. That's the problem. If you had `my_list_of_vecs <- list(c(a = 1, b = 2), c(a = 2, c = 3), c(a = 4, c = 5))` for instance, `lapply(my_list_of_vecs, function(x) x[["a"]])` would return a list as it did with the list of lists.

Comment: @iod I assume you mean `my_list_of_vecs[[3]][["a"]]`. Yup. I see. When asking for non-existent element names, lists return `NULL` and vectors return errors.

Comment: Yep, sorry, my bad.